# jQuery's tooltip issue with position and hover

Tags: jquery, tooltip, hover

I have the following code example (see below). My problem is that the tooltip doesn't show the "old" text after I go away with the cursor - any ideas?

```
<style type="text/css">
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
    var tt = $('#tooltip');
    $('a.tooltip').each(function(){
        $(this).data('title', this.title).attr('title', '');
    }).hover(function(){
        var t = $(this), o = t.offset();
        tt.html(t.data('title')).css({top: o.top, left: o.left}).fadeIn('fast');        
    },
    function(){
        tt.css({display: 'none'});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="tooltip" title="VeryLongTextMoreTextVeryLongText">VeryLongText...VeryLongText</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the mouse enter the `<a>` but *then* it's on the tooltip element, so you need to split the hover, like this:

```
$('body').append('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
var tt = $('#tooltip');
$('a.tooltip').each(function(){
    $(this).data('title', this.title).attr('title', '');
}).mouseenter(function(){
    var t = $(this), o = t.offset();
    tt.html(t.data('title')).css({top: o.top, left: o.left}).fadeIn('fast');
});
tt.mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).stop().hide();
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qJUez/1/), since the mouse over occurs on the `<a>`, add the [`.mouseeenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) to it.  *But*, since you're then over the `#tooltip` on top of the `<a>`, to hide it you need the [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) on the `#tooltip` itself.

What's happening currently is it starts to [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), but as soon as it does so the `mouseleave` event happens (since `#tooltip` isn't a child), so the `display: none;` is triggered (you can use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) here).  The `display:none;` *does* happen, but the next interval of the fade just reverses it, so you end up with a faded-in element.  To prevent that in the `mouseleave` handler above, we've added [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop further fading for this hover.

Comment: Thanks Nick :)  - Works Fine Now